# How do I send arbitrary JSON to node.js without a page reload?

Tags: ajax, node.js, jquery, express

My ultimate goal is to send an arbitrary JSON to node.js when a button is clicked. I currently only know how to send input from a form. Here's some code I put together to send form information:

```
function postForm() {
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // no page reload
    $.post(
      $(this).attr('action'),
      $(this).serialize(),
      function(data) { console.log('Code for handling response here.') },
     'json'
    );
  });
}
```

Where the HTML looks like:

```
<form action='/send' method='post'>
  <input name= "foo" type="radio" value=1>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the relevant express/node.js code looks like:

```
app.post('/send', function(request, response) {
  fs.appendFile('test.txt', JSON.stringify(request.body) + '\n', function(e) {
    if(e) throw e;
    console.log(request.body);
  });
});
```

However, I don't know how to adapt this example to use data that is not from form input. To give context, I'm building a  web-based user study, and I want to send various information collected about the user to node.js. I've tried variants of what was working for the form submission, but none of my attempts have been successful. My impression was that I could just swap out `$(this).serialize()` to any other data that the client can access, but I couldn't get this line of thought to work. I also tried altering some of the many `.ajax()` examples, but those always redirected the page which is undesirable, since my study will lose user-state information if the page refreshes.

I've done decent amount of client and server side programming, but I have next to no knowledge about how ajax works, which is proving rather problematic for solving this! And also rather silly since, often times, that's what glues the two together :)

Comment: Redirection happens because you click on a submit button inside a form. By default this redirects. Remove `<form></form>` tags and use AJAX ( bind it to `click` event on a button ). It will work.

Comment: Use ajax but don't remove the form tags. With the form tags you have progressive enhancement which is a good thing. Instead read the jquery documentation on how to prevent default.

Comment: @slebetman Progessive enhancement to what? Which commonly used browser does not support AJAX?

Comment: @freakish: All modern browsers can be configured to not support ajax by disabling javascript. Also, you're forgetting users like me who often use text based browsers like lynx and links which doesn't have javascript built in. Also, since when is best-practice a bad thing? It's one thing if your site needs lots of work to support progressive enhancement, it's quite another if it already supports progressive enhancement and along comes someone completely gutting it making it incompatible with non-js browsers.

Comment: @slebetman I don't care about users with disabled JavaScript. I care even less about users using text based browsers. After all the number is so small that it might be a statistical error as well. I agree though that using forms here is not lots of work. However I can't agree with that archaic thinking of supporting everything everywhere. We have XXI century. If someone uses horse instead of car/plane then he should know that he won't go far. Yeah, we should support cars and planes.

Comment: @freakish: You may not care but that doesn't mean that others don't care. Don't make assumptions. Some people need to service blind users for example who mostly use text based browsers and among text readers for the blind a lot still don't support javascript properly. You may not need to support blind people but for some it's required by law.

Comment: @freakish: I can't agree with that archaic thinking of not supporting something just because it's not cool. We have XXI century. Buildings can now support disabled users. If an 18th century castle can't support disabled users then we should upgrade them. Not downgrade modern building to look cool at the expense of usability.

Comment: @slebetman It's not because it's cool or not. It's because most of the (JavaScript) programmers work tends to be supporting incompatibile browsers. It's because it halts progress and it is very costly. In order to support these few people. If someone really needs to support them, then that's fine with me. But we should get as modern as possible.

Comment: @slebetman And your 18th century castle example is incorrect, because it actually representes the browser. And yes, they should upgrade the browser. The content however, people, should not be tought how to live in the castle in case something for disabled users break. They fix the castle, they don't learn how to live with it broken.

Comment: @freakish: Your argument is also incorrect. I'm not talking about browser incompatibility at all. I'm talking about the semantic web which is a very modern concept in web architecture. Pure javascript content breaks the semantic web which is why it is considered bad practice. To give another example, even if you don't care about blind users a lot of clients (and bosses) care about search engines. And for Google to crawl your site properly you need to support a non-ajax version.

Comment: ... Google actually does have a method to support ajax site. Go ahead, read their docs.. they support ajax sites by requiring ajax buttons and onclick handlers to link to static, non ajax version of the web page. If you care about SEO, you need to do progressive enhancement properly

Comment: @slebetman Don't worry, once people start to think in a modern way they will create indexing engines to handle it properly. They don't do it, because from they're point of you it is not worth it, because not many sites are solely based on AJAX. But we have an example of FaceBook which is doing just fine. Besides, you won't index data which needs authentication anyway, so this entire "yay, make pages indexable" is an exaggeration.

Comment: @slebetman Don't get me wrong - I do care about progressive enhancment. Let me give you an example how I think. TV shows. Making one for black&white TV and a progressive enhancment for color TVs is fine. But there should be limit for that. Supporting deaf or blind people is a bit too far. I mean people still do that and that's ok, but we should not think about it as a good practice.

Comment: @slebetman Anyway there's no point in arguing about views, especially here at StackOverflow. Thank you for your time and this discussion. :)

Comment: @freakish: Progressive enhancement (otherwise known as unobtrusive javascript) is considered good practice by people much smarter than me or you. It's the whole point behind libraries like jQuery. So I think we really should consider it good practice.

Comment: @freakish: Facebook supports browsers with no javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, sending data is simple – call [`$.post(url, data)`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.post) from the button's `click` handler:

```
$('#somebutton').click(function() {
    var data = { key: 'value', ... };
    $.post('/send', data, function(res) {
        // success callback
    });
});
```

The browser will `POST` to *url* with a URL-encoded serialization of the *data* argument.

```
POST /send HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
...

key=value&...
```

Which Express' `bodyParser` will have no trouble with.  Alternatively, you can tell jQuery to send a JSON serialization of *data*:

```
$.post('/send', data, function(res) {}, 'json');
```

In your case, it really doesn't matter how jQuery transmits the data (URL encoded or JSON), since `bodyParser` automatically deserializes both formats.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a bunch :) Glad that it didn't need a whole lot of overhaul. Out of curiosity, is jQuery's `click` preferred over the HTML `onClick` these days?

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to attach event handlers from script (whether jQuery or not) rather than inlining script in HTML attributes.  [The W3C has further reading.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript)

Comment: add an example of receiving data in express req.body will have data passed to it.

Comment: @chovy: The code the OP already posted should work with no modifications necessary.

Comment: sorry, i was looking at the answer.